# i got error When Customer Name or Agent Name = Null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nullable

and i   got error When Customer Name or Agent Name = Null

```
 var results = db.Users.ToDataSourceResult(request, o => new
            {
                Id= o.Id,
                UserName = o.UserName,
                Email = o.Email,
                PhoneNumber = o.PhoneNumber,
                AgentName = o.Agent.FullName,
                CustomrName = o.Customer.Name 


            });

            return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Please provide a more complete example of what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are attempting to access the property of an object that is Null.  The Agent and Customer properties in this case.  You need to test for nulls before attempting to use them.

```
var results = db.Users.ToDataSourceResult(request, o => new
{
    Id = o.Id,
    UserName = o.UserName,
    Email = o.Email,
    PhoneNumber = o.PhoneNumber,
    AgentName = o.Agent == null ? null : o.Agent.FullName,
    CustomrName = o.Customer == null ? null : o.Customer.Name
});

return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Or if you are using C# 6 you can use the new shorthand

```
var results = db.Users.ToDataSourceResult(request, o => new
{
    Id = o.Id,
    UserName = o.UserName,
    Email = o.Email,
    PhoneNumber = o.PhoneNumber,
    AgentName = o.Agent?.FullName,
    CustomrName = o.Customer?.Name
});

return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you got reference error that is because agent and customer not load in the constructor of user class , you must use lazy loading

```
Public class user{
public user
(
agent=new Agent();
customer=new Customer();
)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this Code and worked 
thanks

```
var results = db.Users.Include("Customer").Include("Agent").ToDataSourceResult(request, o => new
            {
                Id = o.Id,
                UserName = o.UserName,
                Email = o.Email,
                PhoneNumber = o.PhoneNumber,
                AgentName = o.Agent?.FullName,
                CustomrName = o.Customer?.Name


            });

            return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```